# Where is GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE and GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE in iOS 8 SDK?

Tags: ios, opengl-es, glkit

I have written the following code for iOS7 and GLKit which is not working since upgrading to iOS 8 SDK:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, _resolveFrameBuffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE, _multisamplingFrameBuffer);
```

The compiler is unable to find the `GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE` and`GL_READ_FRAMEBUFFER_APPLE` constants.

I think this is related to OpenGL ES 3.0 - Is there a way to use my OpenGL ES 2.0 code which worked just fine on iOS 7? If not, any tips on how to migrate code written against GLKit on iOS 7?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to include the header file defining those values. In C/C++:

```
#include <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

In Objective C:

```
#import <OpenGLES/ES2/glext.h>
```

It seems like some of the OpenGL headers were indirectly included by other commonly used headers in iOS 7, but are not anymore in iOS 8. You were always supposed to include these headers, it just happened to work without before.